# php SEF urls links

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, sef

i have decided to start using SEF urls on a project which is quite large already.

so i'm thinking of converting urls like so.

```
http://localhost/browse.php?cat=people
into
http://localhost/category/people/
```

so i added a RewriteRule to htaccess and Voila the url works but all my css, js, images, links are broken because i have used relative paths throughout the site.

ie. **assets/css/styleshheet.css** rarther than **http://localhost/assets/css/styleshheet.css**

So my question is do you have to use absolute paths throughout your entire site when using SEF urls or is there a trick?

If not, what's the coolest way to implement it?

Comment: Method least likely to result in confusion is absolute URLs. However, you could simply design a rewrite rule to capture anything with `css` etc in it and send it to the right place - but I would *not* recommend this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing jpg gif png js and css to specific folders through htaccess is a very bad idea. Kills your flexibility  and soon you will have thousands of rules defined this way :D

You can define base url of the document like this (put in head section)

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/content/themes/theme1/" />
```

or better start using absulute paths for everything. (IMG sources Link URLs etc.)

For instance Wordpress uses absolute links which is also called permalinks.

Comment: ahh interesting. yes the base tag has worked. Why do you say "or better start using absulute paths for everything"? is there a drawback/disadvantage to using the base tag?

Comment: Yes, if you use a link like <a href="#fragment" > ... you'll be sent to http://www.domain.com/content/themes/theme1/#fragment instead of http://www.domain.com/index.php#fragment , so you must use permalinks for links. Other resources will be loading from the theme root based relative paths.